# What is the difference between the these two scheme macros?

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

provided using mit-scheme

The only modification is from `(cthen (make-syntactic-closure env '(it) (third exp)))` to `(cthen (third exp))`

In brief, what difference does `make-syntactic-closure` make?

```lisp
(define-syntax aif
  (sc-macro-transformer
   (lambda (exp env)
     (let ((test (make-syntactic-closure env '(it) (second exp)))
       (cthen (make-syntactic-closure env '(it) (third exp)))
       (celse (if (pair? (cdddr exp))
              (make-syntactic-closure env '(it) (fourth exp))
              #f)))
       `(let ((it ,test))
      (if it ,cthen ,celse))))))


(let ((i 4))
  (aif (memv i '(2 4 6 8))
       (car it)))
```

```lisp
(define-syntax aif
  (sc-macro-transformer
   (lambda (exp env)
     (let ((test (make-syntactic-closure env '(it) (second exp)))
           (cthen (third exp))
       (celse (if (pair? (cdddr exp))
              (make-syntactic-closure env '(it) (fourth exp))
              #f)))
       `(let ((it ,test))
      (if it ,cthen ,celse))))))


(let ((i 4))
  (aif (memv i '(2 4 6 8))
       (car it)))
```

I tried the two version of macro, but got the same result.

Comment: Better, more consistent indentation would make your code a lot easier to read...

Comment: I've deleted my answer, in order to get the details of the scoping example right.  If we do not close over some subexpression from the form like the identifier `a` and just insert it, the status of that symbol should be exactly like the quoted symbol `let` that we also inserted into the template. Both should be regarded as being in the environment of the macro definition (usually the top level environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A syntactic closure captures the *syntactic environment* and allows identifiers present in it to be used in the form as variables, instead of having a meaning provided by the environment of the macro transformer (It also lets you specify a list of *free names* like `it` in this case that can be set or otherwise used in the macro body and have that binding used in the expanded form; basically it removes those names from the given environment)

An example:

```lisp
(let ((i 4)
      (x '(a b c)))
  (aif (memv i '(2 4 6 8))
       (car x)))
```

With the first version of your `aif` macro, this evaluates to `'a`. With the second version, it generates an error `Unbound variable: x`, because in the macro `cthen` is a list, not a syntactic closure, and `x` is unbound in the macro transformer so it can't be found when the expanded body is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realized it does not do some textual substitution like in C. so the `cthen` is not simply substitute by  `(car x)`. But how does this work step by step. When is `cthen` expanded.

Comment: No, scheme and lisp macros can be thought of as using programmatic structural replacement, not text substitution like the C preprocessor. Far more powerful. The macro returns a s-expression that is treated as code. Look up quasiquoting if you're not familiar with the `,cthen` notation.

Comment: ^ I don't think that's true of syntactic closures; they contain material that isn't S-expression. Bawden's paper has an example implementation in which syntactic closures are labeled vectors that contain functions. Functions are not printable objects; they are opaque code. There is a compile step which invokes these functions in a certain way to obtain Scheme code in which all the local identifiers are renamed; but the paper says that this could just spit out PDP-10 assembly code or whatever.

Comment: Under the Bawden reference model, the reason `x` is unresolved is that since that variable reference wasn't pulled into a syntactic closure, it stays as the symbol `x`. Whereas all local variables in the surrounding scope have been renamed by the compile step; the `x` bound to `(a b c)` is no longer called `x`.